# List of entries in header in text file using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt file where I have text headers and numerical data. I am working with python 2.7, and am using pandas and numpy in my work. The structure of the file is like the picture shown below:

[image]

The data for this file can be gotten from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rlFCXeaJe6DmhwTcvXvlwgD7rYyyf2Ga/view?usp=sharing). In this file, I want to get a list of all tags. For example, in the picture shown above, I want the list to look like the following:

```
[Tag1, Tag1, Tag1, Tag5, Tag5, Tag6, Tag6]
```

At present, I am reading the file using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dum.txt',sep='\t', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

When I try `lst = df.columns.levels[1]`, I get `Index([u'Tag1', u'Tag5', u'Tag6'], dtype='object', name=u'Tag')` as my output instead of the list that I desire.

How can I get a list of tags in my problem, i.e. `[Tag1, Tag1, Tag1, Tag5, Tag5, Tag6, Tag6]` ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) instead of `levels[1]`, then convert to list using `tolist()`:

```
>>> df.columns.get_level_values(1).tolist()
['Tag1', 'Tag1', 'Tag1', 'Tag5', 'Tag5', 'Tag6', 'Tag6']
```

The reason is that `levels[1]` will give you, as you saw, a list of all unique levels, whereas `get_level_values` will actually return:

> Return vector of label values for requested level, equal to the length of the index

Comment: Nice answer! :)  I deleted. +1

Comment: Thanks sacul! Your answer was very helpful. :)